# DynamoDB trigger sometimes giving an error

Tags: aws-lambda, triggers, amazon-dynamodb

I have a lambda trigger on a dynamoDb table event.
Sometimes the trigger is running fine, but sometimes `Function call Failed` error is thrown.
The lambda memory is set to 1024MB and timeout to 05mins. 
The problem is that when the function call failed error comes, no logs are logged on cloudWatch, hence I am not able to debug or identify why the error is coming.

Any insights on how to identify the issue?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend following the example in this article, [New AWS Lambda controls for stream processing and asynchronous invocations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-aws-lambda-controls-for-stream-processing-and-asynchronous-invocations/), to set up some error handling. It will give you some visibility to what is going on.

Basically, use [Lambda Destinations](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/introducing-aws-lambda-destinations/) for failures.